# Modified variational formulation of heat equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, oc.optimization-and-control, calculus-of-variations, integral-operators

The heat kernel $u:\mathbb{R}^n\times (0,\infty)$ is defined as the solution to
$$
u_t = \Delta u,
$$
subject to certain boundary conditions and can alternatively be described, in variational form, as the minimizer of
$$
\int_{t,x} \|u_t - \Delta u\|^2 dtdx,
$$
over all $C^{1,2}((0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}^n)$ functions when those boundary conditions are inforced.

What can be said about the modified variational problem
$$
\min_{u \in C^{1,2}}\int_{t,x} \|u_t(t,x) - \Delta u(t,x)\|^2 
+
\|f(x) - u(t,x)\|^2
dt dx ?
$$
Here $f$ is a fixed $C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function (note it does not depend on $t$).  In general, can we describe $u$ explicitly (or at-least with a power-series (though less-preferably))?

Comment: I think there is a better/more natural variational formulation of parabolic equations due to Brezis and Ekeland. This theory is revisited in a paper of mine here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07672.pdf

Comment: This alternative variational formulation allows for a systematic functional analytic development in the natural parabolic analogue of H^1 which mirrors the classical (variational) theory of elliptic equations found in eg Evans book. The variational problem is uniformly convex in this space, etc....